# Rotating CSS 3 Shapes

Tags: html, css

Are there any ways to rotate CSS 3 shapes at a certain angle?

[Dabblet code here.](http://dabblet.com/gist/9802097)

Comment: [This link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp) will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.shape
    {
        transform:rotate(150deg);
        -ms-transform:rotate(150deg); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform:rotate(150deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `transform:rotate` to your id octagon.

Refer this link: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Answer (score 1):

```css
.object {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
```

You can also set the transform-origin:

```css
object {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform-origin: left;
 }
```

You can change the position to left, right, top or bottom depending on how you want the object to rotate.

Hope this helps!